# report shell script to count and sum from csv files

Tags: command-line, scripts, batch

I need to create a report file from csv files.

I have 160 devices named like `MR001` to `MR160`, there is a folder for each one, all the folders have a unique ID that start with 4, and there is a csv file per day named like `MRNNN_Log_AAAAMMDD-NN.csv`.

the csv file content are like this:

```
MR092/16.11.2017/13:50:50-0300/WLLocalSearch/Error
MR092/16.11.2017/13:51:10-0300/WLLocalSearch/Hit
MR092/16.11.2017/13:51:25-0300/WLLocalSearch/NoHit
MR092/16.11.2017/13:51:35-0300/WLLocalSearch/Error
MR092/16.11.2017/13:51:41-0300/WLLocalSearch/Error
MR092/16.11.2017/13:52:02-0300/RemoteSearch/Captured
MR092/16.11.2017/13:52:53-0300/RemoteSearch/Hit
```

I'm trying with a command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

date=$1

find /path/4*/*_Log_$1*.csv -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "/WLLocalSearch/NoHit" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh
find /path/4*/*_Log_$1*.csv -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "/WLLocalSearch/Hit" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh
find /path/4*/*_Log_$1*.csv -printf 'echo "$(grep -o "/WLLocalSearch/Error" %p | wc -l) %p";' | sh
```

I executed the script like this:

`./report.sh AAAANN`

The output is like this

```
25 /path/path/MR001_Log_20190415-00.csv
4 /path/path/MR002_Log_20190415-00.csv
10 /path/path/MR007_Log_20190415-00.csv
7 /path/path/MR090_Log_20190415-00.csv
etc...
```

the problem is that I have no idea how to sum the total per type and device ID, like this

```
MR001 Hit 10
MR002 Hit 5
```

Etc..

Comment: You can `find` the csv files from filename pattern with date, then `read` multiple variables into an `array` and, at last, output the `array` to screen or to a new csv file